# Trying to dispatch an axios action with a string array as the payload, but keep getting 'undefined' at the reducer?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to web development and as part of a project have made a Django React Redux app. The frontentd has a component with form entry - when a form is submitted, the component calls an action that sends an axios request to a python twitter crawler script in the backend. The script returns a response containing a string array (the tweets are inside the array). I then try to dispatch the array contained in the response.data, as a payload to a reducer. However I keep getting an error saying that the payload of what I have dispatched is undefined.

This is the return statement of the python method that is called - corpus is a string array.

```
return JsonResponse({"results:": corpus})
```

This is the code for the action that sends a GET request to the python method. It's then returned the string array inside a json object.

```
// GET_TWEETS - get list of tweets from hashtag search 
export const getTweets = (hashtag) => dispatch => {
axios
  .get('http://localhost:8000/twitter_search', {
    params: {text: hashtag}
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data); //check if python method returns corpus of tweets
    //const results = Array.from(res.data.results);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_TWEET,
      payload: res.data.results
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
}
```

The console log shows that the object is returned successfully from the python script.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsg5E.png)

This is the code for my reducer. I want my action to contain the string array and then assign that string array to 'tweets' in the state, so that I can return this to a component and then access the array from the component and then display contents of thisx array of tweets on the frontend

```
import { GET_TWEET } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  tweets: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action.payload)
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_TWEET:
      return {
        ...state,
        tweets: [...action.payload]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also, this is some of the code for the component that I want to receive the string array, I hope I have set this part up properly:

```
export class Tweets extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    tweets: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getTweets: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tweets: state.TweetsReducer.tweets
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTweets })(Tweets);
```

Here is the error I get from the console. Console logging the payload of the action also shows that its value is undefined: [undefined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFXK5.png)

I've been trying to solve this for several days now, but am completely lost and I have a hunch the solution to this is pretty simple...

Comment: WHat's the log output for `console.log(res.data.results);` in axios response?

Comment: It gives 'undefined'

Comment: it means you not sending right data  dispatch function. First find the right key, may it is just `res.data` instead of `res.data.results`.

Comment: dispatching just `res.data` gives the same error

Comment: this is simple problem, you need to find how to get data from `res` object